# Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. wi32-x86_64

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

The org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench is not include in the ui.ide jar package. There is also no independent jar file for it.

ERROR::

1. Could that be the reason we get the below error?
2. How can this be resolved?
3. Your latest download have a program executable. Is there no installer for it?

Comment: Please refer : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373883

Comment: can you provide steps how to reproduce this and which version of STS do you use?